# Youtube-DL - Batchfile

Tags: youtube-dl

I have a list of youtube urls.

The list is stored in a batch-file.txt

I would like to download each URL and rename with a given name.m4a

**batch-file.txt**

```
youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= ...' --output '...m4a'
youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= ...' --output '...m4a'
youtube-dl -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v= ...' --output '...m4a'
```

If I run the commands individually, it works.
If I run the batch file via

```
youtube-dl  --batch-file='batch-file.txt'
```

it does not work.

1. What do I need to write in the batch-txt file?
2. How do I call the batch file to download the m4a files simultaneously (if possible)

Many Thanks,
BM

Answer (score 1):

Batch file contains only the URLs, no other parameters.

**batch-file.txt**

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
```

.

Here is the line to run the youtube-dl command starting with leading number 1

```
youtube-dl -ciw -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' --batch-file='batch-file.txt'  -o  '%(autonumber)02d. %(title)s.%(ext)s'
```

Here is the line to run the youtube-dl command starting with leading number 35 (in case you want to continue at another time)

```
youtube-dl -ciw -f 'bestaudio[ext=m4a]' --batch-file='batch-file.txt'  -o  '%(autonumber)02d. %(title)s.%(ext)s' --autonumber-start 35
```

Missing part:

Parallel / Simultaneous Download. But I can live with the approach above.